# Retrieving an attribute from the current node in a node list

Tags: java, xpath

This is my XPath operation:

```
XPathExpression source = xpath.compile("@source/text()");
```

I'm looping over a node list created by another XPath operation on the main document. So I'm calling `source` like this:

```
(NodeList)source.evaluate(list.item(x), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The resulting node list is always empty. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@source/text()` is not valid:  `@source` is an attribute, and attributes do not have child nodes - text or otherwise.

You should use simply `@source`.

(Seeing the XML would help, but I am assuming that `list.item(x)` is an XML element that can have a `source` attribute)